# Echoing mysqli_connect_errno not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Started learning PHP and after learning the basic stuff, which was easy because I learn C++ at school and most of the stuff is similar, I started with mysql. Everything works fine, but I can't get to work the `connect_errno` working.

Copied and pasted this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php into my code with no success.

My few lines of code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

$db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1' , 'root' , '' , 'mydb');

if ($db->connect_errno) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $db->connect_errno);
}

?>
```

I've also tried an example from a tutorial, no success.

**EDIT: ANSWER IS BELOW!**

Comment: What error did you expect? The state variable is going to be zero unless credentials or hostname mismatch. (Also consider the simpler PDO instead of immersing yourself with the fugly mysqli API.)

Comment: mario: If I get no error, it should echo out 0. But it echoes nothing. And I tried changing the name of the database into a non-existing one, still no echo.

Comment: Well the `if()` checks the variable, and like in C++ a zero means false - meaning the if code block and the `echo` will be skipped. If you want the result code printed in any case, remove the condition.

Comment: Yes, @mario, you were right. I thought it should echo a 0, instead of nothing. The response is below, and it worked. Thanks all.

Comment: @mario I believe John did get it right. The accepted answer is the same as John's => `$db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1' , 'root' , '' , 'mydb');`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Still seems largely irrelevant for the code flow. It's an object being returned, not a resource in any case. For connection failures with the hybrid method call there'd even be a differentiating `false` result resulting in two PHP warnings.

Comment: @mario Then the reason why OP's not getting any error output is due to [`error_reporting(0);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) where it should have been `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good catch. I hadn't even anticipated and visualized the 0 there.

Comment: @mario I was puzzled at first, but then when I noticed OP using `(0)` quickly gave it away as to why it did not report errors. There should have been an added note attached to the accepted answer. Am sure the OP will look through our comments and put 2+2 together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mixed the Object-oriented approach and the Procedural approach. Below is the example for the OO approach.

```
$db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1' , 'root' , '' , 'mydb');

if ( $db->connect_errno ) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $db->connect_errno);
}
```

**`error_reporting( 0 );` will suppress errors, so if you're in a debugging workflow and need to see those errors, you'll need to update the error reporting directive to `error_reporting( E_ALL );`.**

*Also, I updated the db name to `mydb` as reflected in the code (I switched that out on my local machine to experiment with connections/errors).*

Comment: A 100k+ member gave the same answer earlier and was deleted because it did not work. Since you're not a 10k+ rep, you're not able to see that answer. Just a quick sidenote.

Comment: Finally it worked! Thank you! I'm still learning, a long way to go seems like!

Comment: @EricKeyte Well that is most bizarre. I don't know why the other answer was deleted. Someone made a comment under that answer that got the person to delete the answer. Oh well, if this works, great. Will +1

Comment: That is quite bizarre! Thanks for the +1. :)

Comment: You're welcome Eric. Have a look through the (new) comments under OP's question. The OP will find the reason as to why errors were not being reported. You could use the comments from there, should you wish to edit your answer and to address the reason why. *Cheers* - P.s.: To address someone personally, add the `@` symbol followed by their name. That way, if you're targeting a specific person, he/she will be notified; just as I did above.

Comment: Hey Fred, how funny, I omitted the `error_reporting( 0 );` directive before editing the code. I forgot to include that in my answer. I'll update now.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a mix of OO and procedural code. mysql_connect does not return an object; it returns a db handle. You can get its error number using the following:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1' , 'root' , '' , 'mydb');
$err = mysqli_connect_errno();
```